# Add meta value on "Upload New Media" page

Tags: wordpress

I´m looking into adding a multiple choice select menu so that the user can
choose an existing category before uploading images, this meta data or parameter has to
be accessible within this action add_action( 'add_attachment') as I´m generating new posts 
from newly uploaded images.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Custom Fields now has options to add custom fields to attachments http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

This should put you in the right direction without having to hack apart your functions.php